# Use reachability file in both framework and Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, reachability, connection

I need to use `Reachability` file in both my *framework and project* to check the network status. But if I add it at both the places, I get a warning saying I have added *duplicate files to two places*.

Comment: try to add it only on framework that you created and check the status in there only

Comment: Your framework should user prefixes at class names, since Objective c does not support name spaces. And this will not be an issue. If u insist on not using prefixes, your framework can use a CocoaPod of Reachability instead of importing the classed by hand.